# FireClient does not work and return to class with any error in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.android, cross-platform

[this is login function but when compiler compile the line where "value" mean its return to Xamarin form without proceeding further
Thank You](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2bJc.png)

```
    async public  Task<User> GetLogin(User info)
    {            
        User login = new User();       
        var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/");
        try
        {
            var value = await firebase.Child("User").OrderByValue().OnceAsync<User>();            
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
            if (info.Username == item.Object.Username && info.Password == item.Object.Password )
            {
                login.Id = item.Object.Id;
                login.Fullname = item.Object.Fullname;
                login.Username = item.Object.Username;
                login.Password = item.Object.Password;
                login.Role = item.Object.Role;
                MasterPage session = new MasterPage(login); 
                return login;
                }
                    else { }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: click on it for the image of issue

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Rather than posting an image, you should copy and paste the code into the question. Not only will that help people understand your question, it'll help other people find your question later!

Comment: You are using try-catch statement, I think that line throws an exception. You could set a breakpoint in the catch statement to find what exception is.

Comment: try this as well but it not send to exception